# Request does not get login forms from spotify

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, request-promise

I want to **scrape** some user data from Spotify. I use a promise request to get the HTML but it doesn't get the full page. It's clear that there is something like an include.

All it gets me is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="app" lang="en" dir="ltr" ng-csp ng-strict-di>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title ng-bind="(&#39;loginTitle&#39; | localize) + &#39; - Spotify&#39;">Spotify</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://accounts.scdn.co/images/favicon.ace4d8543bbb017893402a1e9d1ac1fa.ico">
    <link href="https://accounts.scdn.co/css/index.09e516e04d71c3640f84.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">

    <script defer src="https://accounts.scdn.co/js/index.09e516e04d71c3640f84.js" sp-bootstrap></script>
    <meta ng-non-bindable sp-bootstrap-data='{"phoneFeatureEnabled":false,"user":false,"BON":["0","0",-1340899080]}'>
</head>

<body ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div ng-include="template">
            There should be a login forms right here 
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is how I do it in nodejs

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const $ = require("cheerio");


const url = "https://spotify.com/account/overview";
const email = "strongspider1@gmail.com";
const password = "@Teanoon1";

rp(url).then(function(html){
    console.log(html);
});
```

It's clear for me that there is include but isn't there a way to get full HTML like chrome? I tried setting the user agent to Mozilla/5.0

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const $ = require("cheerio");


const url = "https://spotify.com/account/overview";
const email = "strongspider1@gmail.com";
const password = "@Teanoon1";

const options = {
    uri: url,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0"
    }
}
rp(options).then(function(html){
    console.log(html);
});
```

But it still gives me the same result

Comment: requests won't work since the site is using javascript

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: you have to use headless browsers like puppeteer, selenium, nightmare, etc

Comment: But I would like to get information for my app. The information is not provided by spotify api